# Using whole eggs versus egg whites only

Tags: baking, eggs

I have a recipe that is originally a white cake so uses only egg whites. There is a cake mix involved but other added ingredients such as sour cream and more flour but I’m making a chocolate version and want to add whole eggs. Will this alter the consistency of the cake or just make it richer

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34848, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14214/, https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32511

Answer (score 2):

Extra yolks means more fat which gives the cake ultra moistness! Add the amount of eggs called for in the recipe but add two extra egg yolks.It adds density, fat and most importantly, extra flavor to your mix. Only adding egg whites and not adding the yolks to the cake makes the cake fluffy and whiter!